# I18n website and URL prefix iso639

Tags: url, internationalization, language

I'm adding i18n to my website. For translated pages I add iso639 code of the language like this:

```
http://example.com/en/mypage.php
```

But I'm curious about language code. Should I use iso639-1 (en) or iso639-2 (eng) code ?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639#Relations_between_the_parts

When I check, I see that most of the websites including Wikipedia, uses 2 character language code ? What is the standart or most widely used option for language codes ?

Comment: You should follow these Google's guidelines: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.in/2010/03/working-with-multilingual-websites.html

Google uses it's own intelligence to detech foreign language pages.

Answer (score 1):

Two letter language and country abbreviations are much more widely used than their three letter counterparts.  Here are some examples:

- Locale codes (en_US) such as the [ones used in Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/locales-137662.html)
- Top level country code domains (.us)
- Locale codes [recommended by the w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/ltli/) for use on the web (en-US)